# How to add text on right of subfigure?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, wrapfigure

I am currently writing my thesis. How to add text on right subfigures in latex like this?
[image: Figure]

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm,width=1.2cm]{image1}}\\
   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm,width=1.2cm]{image1}}\\
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A subfloat is basically a minipage with the baseline at the bottom of the image (above the caption).  The main question is how you want to align the text relative to it.

Answer (score 3):

This shows how to align to the top, middle and bottom of the image (assuming you know the height=1.1cm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm,width=1.2cm]{image1}}%
    \hspace{\bibindent}\raisebox{\dimexpr 1.1cm-\height}{Add text here}\\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm,width=1.2cm]{image1}}%
    \hspace{\bibindent}\raisebox{\dimexpr .55cm-0.5\height}{Add text here}\\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=1.1cm,width=1.2cm]{image1}}%
    \hspace{\bibindent}Add text here\\
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score -1):

Hope below suggestion will help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=150pt,width=1.2cm]{image1}} \hspace*{8pt} \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\vskip-150pt your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text here\end{minipage} \\
   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=150pt,width=1.2cm]{image1}} \hspace*{8pt} \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\vskip-150pt your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text hereyour text here your text here your text here your text here your text here\end{minipage}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to increase the figure width, reduce or adjust the minipage width.